# Extruding in Sculpting mode not showing up in other modes

Tags: sculpting

In sculpting mode, I used the mask tool and "transform" to extrude a neck from my misshapen head:
[image]

I then switched to object mode, but the extrusion doesn't show up:
[image]

If I go back to sculpt mode, it is there.

Why doesn't my changes show up in object / edit mode?

Comment: Are you using any modifiers? Multiresolution perhaps?

Comment: I probably should have stated this in my question... I have about 20 hours total of using this application... If I do, I don't know about it... I'll google that and see?